# Get or recreate .class file of java.lang.Class instance

Tags: java, reflection, jvm

I'm using a library which generates some classes at runtime, now I want to export them to look at their bytecode since reflection on the classes doesn't give me enough info about them.

I tried using

```java
generatedClassInstance.getClass().getResourceAsStream(generatedClassInstance.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".class")
```

After this not working I looked at how the class is defined/loaded and it is a simple call to Unsafe#defineClass - so the classes bytes aren't stored in any type of collection.

Comment: Instrument `Unsafe.defineClass`?

Comment: That is the opposite of what I am trying to do, I want the the "source" bytecode that got defined to a java.lang.Class instance

Comment: No, that is exactly what you want: get the bytes passed to `Unsafe.defineClass`.

Comment: Oh sorry you are right, though it raises the question of how I would do that, I know about agents and redefining classes but could you link an article, blog or thread explaining it since I don't have much experience with it

Comment: What library are you using? Most libraries allow to get the bytecode in the first place, without the need to intercept the creation of a runtime class.